# Android Launcher Live Wallpaper

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, launcher, wallpaper

So I'm making an android launcher app. Everything is done, without the live wallpaper support. I can't find anything on the subject. I currently can set any wallpaper, by choosing it from the gallery, but I can't find a way to do it with live wallpapers. I'm using ImageView to display the static wallpaper. Any ideas how to choose and set a live wallpaper? On what should I set it too? I don't think it will work on imageview. Thanks.

Comment: check this link http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html

Comment: just use the Theme_Wallpaper theme for your activity. (Theme_Holo_Wallpaper for 11+ and Theme_DeviceDefault_Wallpaper for 14+)